# How can i use the sum of sums in a having clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sql code, the problem resides in the `HAVING` clause, I have tried to use the alias name but, it won't work someone told me that SQL Server doesn't have that feature of using the alias name in a `HAVING` clause or in a `WHERE` clause, so I've tried to use this one but it isn't working, either.

Please I need your help.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT
   LEFT(RSTab1.EventstartDate,6) MONTHtab1
   ,LEFT(RSTab2.EventstartDate,6) MONTHtab2
   ,RSTab1.TigoMainNumber
   ,(SUM(RSTab2.RevenueRWF)+SUM(RSTab1.Revenue)) Total_RevenueSUM
INTO 
   Subscriber_ALLshared_revenue
FROM 
   DWHAUX1.[SubscriberBase].[dbo].[CDRSubscriber_Revenue] AS RSTab1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
   DWHAUX1.CDRNOrmal.dbo.nrmMSC RSTab2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON RSTab1.TigoMainNumber = RSTab2.CalledPartyNumber
WHERE 
   LEFT(RSTab1.EventstartDate,6) BETWEEN 201310 AND 201403 
   OR LEFT(RSTab2.EventstartDate,6) BETWEEN 201310 AND 201403 
   AND SUM(SUM(RSTab2.RevenueRWF) + SUM(RSTab1.Revenue)) > 680
GROUP BY 
   LEFT(RSTab1.EventstartDate, 6)
   ,LEFT(RSTab2.EventstartDate, 6)
   ,RSTab1.TigoMainNumber
HAVING 
   SUM(SUM(RSTab2.RevenueRWF) + SUM(RSTab1.Revenue)) > 680
ORDER BY 
   COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: What do you want to do in detail? Not sure everyone is understanding your code in terms of what you wanted to do ;)

Comment: You can't have `SUM(SUM())`, that requires nested queries; the inner query does one `GROUP BY` and contains a `SUM()`, and the outer query has another `GROUP BY` and another `SUM()` on the aggregated field returned by the inner query;  `SELECT a, SUM(y) FROM (SELECT a, b, SUM(x) AS y FROM z GROUP BY a, b) AS agg GROUP BY a`.  Could you post some example data to show the logic you mean to implement?

Comment: so the sum in your select is different from the one in your having clause -- '(SUM(RSTab2.RevenueRWF)+SUM(RSTab1.Revenue)) Total_RevenueSUM' vs 'SUM(SUM(RSTab2.RevenueRWF) + SUM(RSTab1.Revenue))' do you really need the second SUM() around the addition that you are doing to get the Total_RevenueSUM value that you want, if not then you can simply use '(SUM(RSTab2.RevenueRWF) + SUM(RSTab1.Revenue))' in your having and where clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  LEFT(RSTab1.EventstartDate,6) MONTHtab1
       ,LEFT(RSTab2.EventstartDate,6) MONTHtab2
       ,RSTab1.TigoMainNumber
       ,(SUM(RSTab2.RevenueRWF)+SUM(RSTab1.Revenue)) as Total_RevenueSUM
       ,COUNT(*) as countRevenue



    FROM DWHAUX1.[SubscriberBase].[dbo].[CDRSubscriber_Revenue]AS RSTab1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN DWHAUX1.CDRNOrmal.dbo.nrmMSC RSTab2 WITH(NOLOCK) 
    ON  RSTab1.TigoMainNumber= RSTab2.CalledPartyNumber
    WHERE LEFT(RSTab1.EventstartDate,6) BETWEEN 201310 AND 201403 
    OR LEFT(RSTab2.EventstartDate,6) BETWEEN 201310 AND 201403 
    GROUP BY LEFT(RSTab1.EventstartDate,6)
            ,LEFT(RSTab2.EventstartDate,6)
            ,RSTab1.TigoMainNumber
) as Z
WHERE Total_RevenueSUM >680
ORDER BY countRevenue DESC
```

Comment: Thanks m hasan it works very nice, you did great job.